# Changing wave header in mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, header, recording, wave

Is it possible to change the wave header in an existing mp3 file? I need it to be 8 or 16 bits per sample.

Any tips about how to proceed? I am totally stuck.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which wave header are you referring to? Are you talking about the [frame header](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)? In any case, it doesn't contain a bits-per-sample field because such information would be meaningless to store in the compressed mp3 stream.
It's up to the decoder/player to decide how many bits to use per sample when generating an uncompressed PCM stream from the mp3.
In case you mean that you've slapped a RIFF header onto an mp3 file to be able to import it into various old programs, you can find the format of that header [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Comment: Thank you very much, i guess then that a wav file does contain a bit per sample field, right?